# Difficult to read text in Android 2.x Dialogs

Tags: android

The following code will make a dialog box with a spinning progress indicator and some text that says "Loading...":

```
    final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context );
    dialog.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.loading));
    dialog.show();
```

On stock 2.3 and on Samsung TouchWiz, the text is black against a dark background and nearly impossible to read.

If I use `dialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true)`, I get a white dialog with black text.  This works great on stock 2.3 and Samsung TouchWiz, but does NOT work on HTC Sense, where the text is visible but the spinner is white on white.

What is the proper way to make a simple ProgressDialog with visible text and progress indicator that will work across all custom skins?

Answer (score 0):

Htc messed with `ProgressDialog` code. You can always extend `ProgressDialog` to your own `CustomProgressDialog`. From there you can force your own background from `onDraw`() or get the BackgroundColor and set the TextColor to a opposite Color so it's nice to read. On htc sense textColor=White on stock Black and so on..

To do that i strongly recommend to read `ProgressDialog` code from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Framework/kindleflow/android/app/ProgressDialog.java.htm) and also if you can get your hands to htc sence  `ProgressDialog` even better.